# Adding timeout to a command in an FTP client

Tags: c#, ftp

I have this piece of code:

```
string test_dir = ftp.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/test";

if (!ftp.DirectoryExists(test_dir))
{
    ftp.CreateDirectory(test_dir);
}
```

where ftp is instance from the FtpConnection class.
However it crashes and I get 421 Idle timeout (600 seconds) closing control connection error. Why is this happening? In some cases it doesn't happen, and in some it does. How to fix it?

How to add timeout to a command?

Comment: It sounds like it happens because the FTP server takes too long to respond. Does it only happen after a very long wait? Hard to say how to fix it. It depends if the error is on your side (i.e. you sometimes use the wrong settings) or on the server side (i.e. the server is sometimes non-responsive). More investigation is probably required.

Comment: @JamesGaunt How would I investigate this? I only looked at the exception VS thres, and in Fiddler.

Comment: I'd check to make sure you're using the right FTP settings when the error occurs. Perhaps try to connect to the FTP site manually using the same settings. If it only happens intermittently using the exact same settings it suggests to me it's an issue on the FTP server which would require looking at how that is configured.

Comment: @JamesGaunt Well since it sometimes goes well, without throwing the error, I guess the settings are ok.

Comment: Then it suggests the server isn't?  But even so are you sure the settings are _always_ the same?  Best not to guess anything in this kind of situation.